# JComboBox exclusive selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm making an interface where I have multiple JComboBoxes that have the same list of values and I want to make an exclusive selection of these values (I don't want two JCB to select the same item), but I have no idea of a way to do it.

I thought of something like buttonGroup (from JRadioButton) but I don't find something like that. Must I do a custom class or is there some magical java-stuff to do it ?

Comment: After selecting a value from a JCB, remove it from the other JComboBoxes.

Comment: But then the user could empty all JCBs by selecting every value once on the same JCB.

Comment: Once the user selects another value, the old value must be restored back then.

Comment: I thought about that, but in my mind, it was too complicated for what it was. Wanna do it anyway and post it here for little buddies who also want to do it.

Comment: You could enable multiple selection on one [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).  Otherwise, the easiest thing to do is let the user pick his selections, then click a JButton that says, "I'm done".  The action listener of the button would check for the unique selections of the JComboBoxes.

Comment: I'll do something like that, because I don't have time to do it properly (to complicate things, I'm using JCB in a JTable, which is pretty tricky to modify the JCB content - you can only access the selected items, not the JCB itself - ) I will temporarily change to background to multi-selected items to RED, will do the trick